# scikit learn Как предугадать следующие числа, из последовательности?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Есть массив чисел, допустим `[2,1,2,2,1,2,..2,1,1]` , как продолжить этот массив? Какие методы машинного обучения лучше подойдут?

Comment: В массиве могут быть только единицы и двойки? Т.е. это задача классификации или регрессии? Ещё не помешала бы дополнительная информация- что это за ряд, что он из себя представляет? Это “time series”?

Comment: @MaxU , числа могут быть либо 1 и 2, либо от 1 до 8 (включительно), и это не временные ряды

Comment: значения от 1 до 8 - дискретные (квантующиеся) или любое вещественное число из этого диапазона? Ваш числовой ряд от чего-нибудь зависит? Обратите внимание на последний абзац ответа от @passant и уточните ваш вопрос. С такой формулировкой вопроса сложно что-либо посоветовать...

Comment: последовательность ни от чего не зависит, можно считать, что она рандомная числа все целые могут быть либо только 1 и 2, либо от 1 до 8

Comment: тогда вам должно подойти: `np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 9), N)`, где `N` - число элементов... ;)

Comment: @MaxU , это дело понятное.. что имея рандомный массив в предсказаниях не будет смысла. Но рандомный массив я привел только в качестве примера, на деле закономерности будут. Но дело в том, что они не известны. И проблема собственно и заключается в том, чтобы предсказать значения не зная заранее данных.

Answer (score 5):

Если ряд состоит из "1" и "2" и никакой дополнительной информации о ряде нет, то единственное, что можно сделать - искать вероятность появления каждого из значений, а потом используя полученные доли генерировать случайным образом значения.

Можно пойти чуть дальше, и пытаться выявить частоты появления для пар, триад, квартетов и т.д.

Если есть (или можно извлечь) некоторую дополнительную информацию, (ну, например, что вероятности появления "1" и "2" меняются со временем, т.е. имеется тренд или присутсвует сезонность) то можно пытаться их (тренд или сезонность) обнаружить с помощью соответствующих методов.

Если появление "1" и "2" обусловлено какими-то другими факторами, то можно пытаться строить классификатор где факторы - независимые переменные, а ваши "1" и "2" - просто метка класса.

В любом случае, главное правило Data Science - данные не существуют сами по себе. Осмысленные анализ данных можно проводить только имея представление о семантическом контексте имеющихся данных.
Удачи.

Comment: Последний абзац- прямо в точку! +1

Comment: моя проблема и заключается в том, что данных заранее я не знаю. И предсказывать их нужно в слепую.

Comment: "В  слепую" можно только угадывать. А если предсказывать - то так или иначе надо данные изучать. Кстати - "заранее" знать и не надо. Можно и по мере поступления данных их изучать, в том числе методами, упомянутыми выше.